# Command to add specific time on a filename?

Tags: rename, batch-rename, exif

I just returned from trip and try to organize a minimum photos taken by my wife and me with 4 devices : our 2 smartphones and 2 cameras.

I choose to rename all the files with PyRenamer (EXIF) like this : YYYYMMDD_HHMMSS.jpg

Both smartphones and one camera were at the local time, no problem. But my wife's camera had a time shift of 5:46.

My question is simple : how could I add 5:46 to each file ?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Did you already rename the files? In a recursive directory or flat?

Comment: I already rename all the files (before IMG_2655.JPG and now 20161019_112301.jpg for example) and the shifted ones are in a subdirectory.

Comment: The command [`rename`](http://askubuntu.com/questions/58546/how-to-easily-rename-files-using-command-line) might be able to do the job, but I'm guessing you would need to create/put together a command to do what you want to do and I'm not sure what you would have to do.

Comment: 20161019_112301.jpg + 5:46 = 20161019_170901.jpg ;) And thank you but that's the problem : I'm trying to find the proper format

Comment: Can be done with a small script. I will look into today or tomorrow if no one answered it yet :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**NOTE**: the following does not change either the EXIF data or the actual timestamp of the files - just their names. It may be preferable to change all three consistently (perhaps possible using `exiftool`?)

---

It seems to be possible using the perl based `prename` / `rename` command, using `strptime` to read in the formatted time string, then `strftime` to write it back out after adding an offset - in seconds (implicitly converted to a Time::Piece object).

Based on comments, by *"my wife's camera had a time shift of 5:46"* you appear to mean 5 hours 46 minutes (rather than, say, 5 minutes 46 seconds), and you require a shift (forward) of 5 x 3600 + 46 x 60 = 20760 seconds. So you could do:

```
prename -vn -- '
BEGIN{use Time::Piece};
s/\d+_\d+/(20760+Time::Piece->strptime($&, "%Y%m%d_%H%M%S"))->strftime("%Y%m%d_%H%M%S")/e
' *.jpg
20161019_112301.jpg renamed as 20161019_170901.jpg
```

The `-n` flag is for testing - remove it when you are **sure** the command is performing the right conversion.

See this related question [How can I batch convert folder names from one date format to another](https://askubuntu.com/a/813647/178692)

Comment: Sorry for not being precise but it's exactly that, a forward of 20760 seconds. I'll try that (my first use of Perl) and let you know ... thanks a lot !