# Rename and convert dates in filename without file extension

Tags: command-line, bash, rename, date, mv

My set of files are named according to GMT time zone. I successfully renamed and converted all files into the required time zone using the following steps.

**1.** This code removes all file extensions that are .gif `rename "s/.gif//g" *`

**2.** This code converts and renames all files   `for f in *; do mv -v -- "$f" "$(date -d "$f" '+%Y%m%d%H%M')"; done`

- Example conversion: `‘15Z29Aug2017’ -> ‘201708292030’`

Unfortunately I have to set the extension .gif once again to all files using `for f in *; do mv "$f" "$f.gif"; done`

How exactly can I skip the file extension removal by editing my code in step 2 ?

Step 2 taken from: [How can I batch convert folder names from one date format to another](https://askubuntu.com/questions/813638/how-can-i-batch-convert-folder-names-from-one-date-format-to-another/813830#813830)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All you need is to strip `.gif` from `$f` and put it back on:

```
for f in *; do mv -v -- "$f" "$(date -d "${f%%.gif}" '+%Y%m%d%H%M')".gif; done
```

`${f%%.gif}` takes variable `f` and removes the last (hence `#` two times) occurence of `.gif` in it, so even a strange filename like `1.gif2.gif` would only get his last `.gif` removed. This amazing feature is called **Bash Parameter Expansion** and when you search it by this name you can read all about its dazzling power, e. g. on [this Bash FAQ](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/073) – it's capable of so much more!

Comment: Oh so simple!!! I'm embarrassed. Where can I find a document that teaches me these tricks?

Comment: @ChintanSheth You have to promise to me to just use bash's superpower for good. ;-) I edited it in.