# Change date format in filenames

Tags: command-line, scripts, batch-rename

I am receiving emails, the filename format is this (It is Unix format for date + `.report-server`)

```
1509106656.32538_1.report-server
```

Now I have several emails. I want to format all file names with new date time format like this.

```
dd-mm-yyyy.report-server
```

Comment: Why do you want `dd-mm-yyyy`? See mandatory [xkcd comic about ISO 8601](https://xkcd.com/1179/) :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this:

```bsh
for i in *.report-server; do echo mv "$i" "$(date -d@${i%%.*} +%d-%m-%Y.${i##*.})"; done
```

This loops over the `.report-server` files in the current directory and for every file prints a line like

```
mv 1509106656.32538_1.report-server 27-10-2017.report-server
```

where you can check the file name. If it does what you want, simply remove `echo` from the command and run it to perform the renaming.

**Be careful**! If you end up having multiple files with the same date `mv` will (by default) silently overwrite the first ones. If you want to preserve the (presumably unique) `.32538_1` part, change `${i##*.}` to `${i#*.}` in the command. If you want `mv` to ask before overwriting files, add the `-i` option.

Comment: Its working thanks. i change **mv** to **cp**  . And yes i noticed that but i am receiving email per day, it will work fine.

Comment: @DaviD If you want to have the files sorted correctly I recommend using `yyyy-mm-dd` format instead – replace `%d-%m-%Y` with `%F` for that.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following script as a hint:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
for i in *.report-server; do
    timestamp=$(echo $i | cut -d. -f1)
    output_date=$(date +'%d-%m-%Y' -d @$timestamp)
    mv "$i" "${output_date}.report-server"
```

Comment: Yes there was error   **extra operand ‘@1507285570’**

Comment: @MukeshSaiKumar +1 You're welcome!

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way to do it using perl-based `rename` or `prename` (essentially a duplicate of [How can I batch convert folder names from one date format to another](https://askubuntu.com/a/813647/178692), with different format specifiers):

```
$ rename -n -- '
  BEGIN{use Time::Piece};
  s/(\d{10})\.\d{5}_1/Time::Piece->strptime($1, "%s")->strftime("%d-%m-%Y")/e
' *.report-server
rename(1509106656.32538_1.report-server, 27-10-2017.report-server)
```

Remove the `-n` (or change to `-v` if you want verbose output) when you are happy that it is doing what you want.